Increase the dimensions of the loaded gltf model in Three js
I loaded a 3d model with gltf extension using GLTFLoader in Three.js.
const loader= new GLTFLoader();

    //background box
    loader.load('../../assets/backgroundBox.gltf',function(gltf){
      scene.add(gltf.scene);
      gltf.animations;
      gltf.scene.rotation.z=Math.PI/2;
      gltf.scene.rotation.y=Math.PI/2;
      gltf.scene.castShadow=true;
      gltf.scenes;
      gltf.cameras;
      gltf.asset;
    },function(err){console.log('An error occurred in loading files')});

Now i want to add an event listner which when windows get resized, the dimensions of loaded model changes simultaneously with respect to window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight.
window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
      const width = window.innerWidth;
      const height = window.innerHeight;
      camera.aspect = width / height;
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
      renderer.setSize(width, height);
      
    });

I added an event listner to window, however i couldn't figured out how to change for the loaded model


…i couldn't figured out how to change for the loaded model

Exactly the same how you scaling objects classically, in your scenario difference only is, that additionally you listen resizing.
window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
    const width = window.innerWidth;
    const height = window.innerHeight;
    camera.aspect = width / height;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize(width, height);
    
    if (loadedModel) {
        const scaleFactor = Math.min(width, height) / 600; //for example
        loadedModel.scale.set(scaleFactor, scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
    }
});

